# Running rsh command under the root account

Tags: windows, root, rsh

I have two machines running Solaris 9 (192.168.2.9) and Windows XP (192.168.2.5). I need to run the following command on the Windows machine:

```
rsh 192.168.2.9 -l root pwd
```

To be able to run this command I've created the `/etc/hosts.equiv` file on the UNIX machine, which contains:

```
192.168.2.5 xp.user
```

where `xp.user` is the name of the active XP account, under which the `rsh` command connects.

The command gives the following messages:

```
192.168.2.9: permission denied
rsh: can't establish connection
```

I tried to change the UNIX user to `notroot`:

```
rsh 192.168.2.9 -l notroot pwd
```

The command gave the same result:

```
192.168.2.9: permission denied
rsh: can't establish connection
```

But when I created the file `/home/notroot/.rhosts` with the same contents as `/etc/hosts.equiv` the result was OK:

```
/home/notroot
```

Both the `hosts.equiv` and `.rhosts` files are identical and were created in the UNIX `vi` editor. The empty lines are added at the end of each file. The properties of the files are:

`/etc/hosts.equiv` - group: root; owner: root; permissions: owner: RW

`/home/notroot/.rhosts` - group: other; owner: notroot; permissions: owner: RW

The choice of `rsh` protocol and the root account doesn't depend on me.

So, how can I run the `rsh` command under the root account?

Comment: Have you tries putting the mentioned `.rhosts` under ~root?

Comment: I have no such directory.

Comment: you root user doesn't have a home directory (which is what the tilda stands for - ~userxyz/ is home directory of userxyz)?

Comment: Yes, it works!
In my system the home directory for root is "/" (which is the default, AFAIK), so I placed .rhosts there.
But I also had to change the permissions of the file to 'group: root; owner: root; permissions: owner: RW'.
With its original permissions (group: other; owner: notroot; permissions: owner: RW) it didn't work.
Thank you for the advice!

Comment: `/` is **not** the default home directory for root, and should never be set so! The usual location of root's `$HOME` is `/root`.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely agree that the root's home directory should be set to /root. But many sites and tutorials clearly state that the Solaris' root home directory is '/', and some of them also give instructions how to change it to /root (no need to mention them, just google). Besides, I've checked several servers running Solaris 9, and none of them has the /root directory. I think it's very doubtful that the admins who set them up changed /root to '/' after or during installation. Doesn't that mean the default location?

Comment: Interesting, IMHO the tutorials are flawed - mixing root's configuration with system data is just asking for troubles (the next step being: *remove all directories, just store everything in `/`*).

Comment: Hmm... I'll put it another way: the tutorials just say that '/' is the **default** location, not the **right** one. And some of them suggest how to improve the situation by changing it to /root, exactly as you said.)))

Comment: Oh ok, I misread your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround is placing the `.rhosts` file into root's home directory (see comments under the question).